# org-mode error: Region to sort contains a level above the first entry

Tags: org-mode, sorting

When calling `org-sort-entries` on an outline item, I get the error

> Region to sort contains a level above the first entry

with no indication of what or where the problem is.

What does this error mean, and how do you fix it?

Answer (score 3):

Take an example like this, with a TAB before the 'd' - if you call `org-sort-entries` on the 'a', you'll get the error - the '*[TAB]d' seems to confuse the function.

```
* a
** c
*   d
** b
```

You can do a regexp search through the file to find problems like this, e.g. put this at the top of your file and hit `C-x C-e` after it (`eval-last-sexp`):

```
(re-search-forward "^[*]+[\t]")
```

Comment: I've got the same problem, but when I try the expression above I get `(void-function find-regexp)`. Am I missing something or is this function not part of emacs? If the latter one please provide the function. Besides that, I find the whole issue rediculous. Why is org-mode not more robust? Either skipping the error or point to the problem line, so it can be fixed manually.

Comment: @JensLange ah, I forgot that was an alias I had made for `re-search-forward` - was trying to make things easier to remember and discover. But yes, maybe there's something we could do to patch org-mode for this error...

Comment: I just got this even though the search failed: ```Lisp error: (search-failed "^[*]+[\11]")```. What should be done to fix the problem in that case ?

Answer (score 0):

Simplified: Org thinks that your file has **several top-level entries**. As written above, this can happen if you have an org-file like

```
* task 1
** subtask 1
* task 2
** subtask 3
```